# What's error in below code of wrapping the path in double quotes?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

Following is my PHP code line:

```
$nic = "'".ADMIN_SITE_URL."'assets/img/watermark.png'";
$client->setWatermark($nic, 105, 148);
```

Here `ADMIN_SITE_URL` is a constant and I want to concatenate a string to this constant and wrap the whole sting into singlee quotes as this is going to be asigned as a parameter into a method named setWatermark(). But I'm not able to do it. Getting the error as:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in pdf_test_question_paper.php on line 83
Errors parsing pdf_test_question_paper.php
```

I'm not getting why this is happening. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're producing a string that looks like `"'ADMIN_SITE_URL'assets/img/watermark.png'"`. Note the extra `'` after `URL`.

Comment: @meagar:Thanks for your suggestion. Can you provide me the correct string enclosed in single quotes, please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try That

```
$nic = "'".ADMIN_SITE_URL."assets/img/watermark.png'";
```

Comment: :I tried your code but still it's not working. Giving me the same error.

Comment: what is the output of `ADMIN_SITE_URL`

Comment: :Thanks for your help. It worked for me. Actually I was the one who was doing it wrong way :)